# IIS SMTP only shows one IP to select from

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-6

Setup is 2 virtual SMTP servers in an IIS 6.0.

Cannot add second IP to second virtual SMTP server (or to the first server really).
The General > IP address only shows only one IP.

Tried configuring the second IP in the same network card, as well as creating (it is a VM) a second network adapter, creating a second TeamNic (NIC must go trough Teams in this case) and setting up the second ip there. No luck.

After restarting the server IIS SMTP still only sees one of the IPs, the original one.

In the dropdown there are only "all unasigned" and one of the IPs.

What should I do for the second IP to also show in the IP addresses menu of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is worth it for somebody else, what I did was setting up the second IP in the same Network card ( it works as well with an aditional card, but  it isn't really needed).

So now each relay talk with the other one via FQDN with TLS 1.2 which was the goal.